# Calico deployment not saving tolerance for master node

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubeadm, calico, kubectl

I was trying to setup a Kubernetes Cluster using Amazon EC2 and Kubeadm.
I created a '**t2.large**' EC2 instance based on Ubuntu 18.04 AMI. Setup kubeadm, kubelet, kubectl and docker as the container runtime.

Ran the `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16` command and the control-planes like 'kube-api-server', 'scheduler', 'controller',etc got created.

For the Container Network Interface, I was intending to use **Calico**.
I followed the following link to install Calico in my Kubernetes cluster: https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart

I ran the following commands to install Calico:
`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`
`kubectl create -f https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml`
`kubectl create -f https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/custom-resources.yaml`

As soon as these commands are run, the calico pods will get created, but some pods are in pending state:

[image]

After describing the pod, it says that it's unable to tolerate the taint `node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane`.

In the instructions from the link, it's mentioned that we need to untaint the master node for the pods to get scheduled.

As an alternative, I tried to edit the deployment ** calico-kube-controllers** and add the following tolerance in order to schedule the pod in the master node:

```
- key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
  operator: "Exists"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

The solution works for a moment. The pod gets scheduled into the master node for a while. After few minutes, the pod is terminated and again goes back to pending state.

When I edited the deployment again, the line of code that I added for the tolerance is not there anymore. I can't find a clear reason why this is happening.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Since you're using the operator, the reconciliation loop is "fixing" your edits; you'll need to edit that [`Installation` custom resource](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/installation/api#operator.tigera.io/v1.InstallationSpec) and add `controlPlaneTolerations:`

Comment: Also, please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: @mdaniel - Could you please explain this a bit specific? Didnt catch the idea pretty well. Maybe you can post the solution as an answer.

Comment: I don't have a "solution," and I don't use their operator in order to test it. But that `kubectl apply` of `custom-resources.yaml` created an `Installation` object, but their object doesn't meet your needs. So you can download that file and edit it, or `kubectl edit $whatever_the_api_resource_name_is_of_Installation` to just patch the one that is in-cluster

Comment: Mmm. Okay
Thank you.